# postgresql search jsonb array items

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jsonb

I want to find rows base on data in the jsonb data type column with postgresql, is this the correct syntax to do search with array items?

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE diff_data @> '{"rfc6902": [{"op": "replace", "path": "/status/"}, "value": "0"]}';
```

output first row in below table

table

```
id | diff_data  
1  | {"rfc6902": [{"op": "replace", "path": "/status", "value": "0"}]}
2  | {"rfc6902": [{"op": "replace", "path": "/status", "value": "1"}]}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: first row in above data example  table

Comment: just: `select * from table  where diff_data = '{"rfc6902": [{"op": "replace", "path": "/status", "value": "0"}]}'::jsonb`

Comment: @OtoShavadze so the `@>` is wrong?

Comment: if you compare whole json's , both will do same . Not sure which one is faster, though...

Comment: @OtoShavadze thank you so much, I will try it